# User control error: class not found in WPFBindingNavigaorControl.WPFBindingNavigator control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I trying to create a WPF binding navigator control that I want to place in my custom libraries project. It gives me the following error:

```
Error   1   The type name 'WPFBindingNavigatorControl' does not exist in the type 'WPFBindingNavigatorControl.WPFBindingNavigatorControl'
```

Now here is the xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFBindingNavigatorControl.WPFBindingNavigatorControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="45" d:DesignWidth="375" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ImageButton;assembly=ImageButton" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="47*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="87*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="32*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="54*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="51*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="54*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <my:ImageButton Name="btnFirst" Image="/images/Go-first.png" ImageHeight="NaN" ImageWidth="NaN" />
    <my:ImageButton  Grid.Column="1" Name="btnPrevious" Image="/images/Go-previous-view.png" Margin="6,0,0,0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Margin="6,10,8,12" Name="txtGoTo" />
    <Label Content="Of" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,8,3,9" Name="label1" />
    <Label Content="Label" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,8,0,9" Name="lblTotalRowCount" />
    <my:ImageButton Grid.Column="5" Name="btnNext" Image="/images/Go-next.png" Margin="0,0,9,0" />
    <my:ImageButton Grid.Column="6" Name="btnLast" Image="/images/Go-last.png" />
</Grid>
```

Right now, this also uses another user control that I created: ImageButton. This class is in another project in my testing solution. I have reset all my projects' Target Framework to the same thing: .NET Framework 4. I still get the same xaml error. I know I have done something wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Ed Cohen

Comment: Verify in code behind of this `UserControl`, the class name is same as that in `Xaml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the name of the class to a different name than the current namespace, like this:

```
namespace = WPFBindingNavigatorControl
class = WPFBindingNavigatorControl
```